# Blackberry hide fields

Tags: blackberry, field

I have a dropdown list in which I select how many people are going to a party. When the user changes the value of the dropdown list, I want as many fields as the number selected to appear and hide the rest.

But I don't know how can I hide or delete fields because I don't know their index.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you will need to have the fields you want to hide as a global variables.

You will also need to get the value the user has selected and use that to work out what fields should be removed or added.

One way would be to add all the fields in order to a vector or an array when the screen is initialised. Once the user has selected a value you could iterate through the fields and use the current index of the list and the user selected value to work out if the field should be removed or added.

Comment: This is BlackBerry, meaning j2me - there's no ArrayList available.

Comment: You're right.I've edited the answer to reflect that. I have ArrayList added in a utility project so I am able to use it on blackberry.

Comment: thanks! can you explain me how have you added the ArrayList utility in a utility project? thanks

Comment: I simply got the implementation of ArrayList from the java source and added it to my utility project. You will also need the following AbstractCollection, AbstractList, Collection, Comparable, ConcurrentModificationException, Iterator, List and ListIterator. You will need to change a few imports so it uses the Blackberry api classes instead of java where necessary. And I made ArrayList implement net.rim.device.api.util.Persistable so it can be used in persitent store. Now you can use ArrayList on blackberry!

Answer (score 0):

If you have the field objects, then use Field.getIndex() to find the index of each field within its manager.

Comment: so i need to have each object as a global variable inside the MainScreen class in order to do this,do i?

Comment: I can certainly see doing it with a field on your MainScreen.  A static field shouldn't be necessary, based on what you've described.